# Eclipse Maven Plugin not working then after update cannot start Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, plugins, proxy, corporate-policy

I had the following Eclipse details on Windows 10:

Eclipse IDE For Enterprise Java and Web Developers (includes incubating components):

Version 2023-03 (4.27.0)
Build id 20230309-1520

It had been working fine for years. All of a sudden, Maven Build is not working properly. When I run Maven Build, I can tell it is running but no output is showing in the console, and I can only see the following:

```
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.  
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation  
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.  
SLF4J: Class path contains SLF4J bindings targeting slf4j-api versions 1.7.x or earlier.  
SLF4J: Ignoring binding found at [jar:file:/C:/path-to-folder/Eclipse_23_03_64bit_1/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.701.20230209-1606/jars/maven-slf4j-provider-3.8.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]  
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#ignoredBindings for an explanation.  
[debug] execute contextualize  
[debug] execute contextualize  
[debug] execute contextualize  
[debug] execute contextualize
```

I did some research and thought the solution was to update the Maven Plugin. I ran the update, and it took about an hour to update. I received several errors during this process, and when it was done, I could not start Eclipse. First, I got this when I tried to start it the first time:

```
An error has occurred. See the log file path-to-folder\eclipse\jee-2021-06\eclipse\configuration\1705625850636.log.
```

[click here to open the log file](https://github.com/tarekahf/EclipseIssues/blob/main/1705625850636-mod.log)

Then I got this error:

```
The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library.
```

I found several articles about fixing `eclipse.ini` but nothing worked.

Please help me to troubleshoot this error.

## Update 1:

Added the log file:

[click here to open the log file](https://github.com/tarekahf/EclipseIssues/blob/main/1705625850636-mod.log)

I did the additional analysis, and it seems that the files under `eclipse/configuration` were not updated correctly during the Maven Plugin Update process probably due to corporate proxy issues as I saw several errors in the Eclipse Errors Log View indicating items not found, URL cannot be reached, or files cannot be downloaded. I cannot open Eclipse now and I don't know where Eclipse logs are stored.

## Update 2:

In downloaded and installed Eclipse IDE for Java Enterprise and Web Application Development 2023-12. It was successful, and I noticed some of the configurations from the previous install were restored and I think this is because Oomph Dereference Recorder tool. Also, I noticed that Maven was updating, so looks like maven is pre-installed with this Eclipse. I Proceeded to installing SVN and got this error in the as `Subversive SVN Integration for the M2E Project` could not be installed, so it was  left out:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Subversive SVN Integration for the M2E Project (Optional) 4.8.0.v20220904-1901 (org.eclipse.team.svn.m2e.feature.group 4.8.0.v20220904-1901)
  Missing requirement: Subversive SVN Integration for the M2E Project (Optional) 4.8.0.v20220904-1901 (org.eclipse.team.svn.m2e.feature.group 4.8.0.v20220904-1901) requires 'org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.m2e.scm [1.0.0,2.0.0)' but it could not be found
```

## Update 3:

I did a detailed analysis and found the following errors in the workspace logs:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui 4 0 2024-01-20 17:08:44.188
!MESSAGE Unable to read repository at https://osspit.org/eclipse/subversive-connectors/content.xml.
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException: Unable to read repository at https://osspit.org/eclipse/subversive-connectors/content.xml.
...
...
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Which is clearly a corporate proxy issue. I extracted the corporate certificate from the browser and added it to an existing cacerts file as trust store, configured eclipse to point to this cacerts file from `eclipse.ini`, and all problems installing plugins were resolved. I am still checking the status now.

Any help would be appreciated. I am now proceeding with troubleshooting.